# Why is it a bad idea to include Groovy code in a GSP?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Can someone please explain why it is that in most of the documentation I’ve read everyone drums home the theory that it’s bad to include code in a Grails GSP yet, even in the same doc you find varying degrees of logic in a GSP? Is there some unwritten rule as to how much code a GSP should have or is it a judgement call as to what you think is safe?

TIA

Comment: It's a bad idea to include TOO MUCH of code inside. The thing is, you can not test the code inside the GSPs transparently.

Comment: think gsp has also mem size restriction - http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GSP-Size-is-limited-to-64KB-any-way-to-fix-this-td3919762.html

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons. The main reason is because Grails roughly follows the MVC pattern, with a service layer added in. Most of your business logic should be in services or data services. Your controllers should only be concerned with taking in parameters (preferably in command objects), calling services, routing, and rendering, the views should just render the model sent from the controller. The controllers should just have templating logic, loops, and conditionals, but nothing that requires a transactions or bean references. Organizing you logic this way gives you a separation of concerns, and like the previous comment mentioned it makes everything easier to test.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks